# How do I add a song to many other songs?

Tags: audio

I want to add a small jingle tune to the beginning of multiple songs.

I tried to use something like `audacity` do it manually, but it is very slow as I have more than 1000 songs to process. How can I do that faster ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How can I join / concatenate many audio files?

You'll want "the swiss-army knife of sound processing programs", [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/).

> SoX is a cross-platform (Windows, Linux, MacOS X, etc.) command line utility that can convert various formats of computer audio files in to other formats. It can also apply various effects to these sound files, and, as an added bonus, SoX can play and record audio files on most platforms.

You don't specify a platform that you are attempting this on or any other specifics such as format, so this is a general outline of how to go about invoking `sox` to make these joins:

```
for filename in directory_of_songs:
    sox jingle.wav filename.wav filename-joined.wav
```

That is, if supplied with more than one `input` filename `sox` will concatenate (join) them into the `output` file, as [per the `sox` documentation](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Sox is awesome, I knew ffmpeg ! But I didn't know that we could also concatenate with it : take a look at https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate.